# Why can't I set two vhost in my apache?

Tags: apache-2.4, hostname

Apache was installed on my debian,i want to bind two domain name with different directroy.

```
cat  /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1  hwy.local  www.hwy.local  
127.0.0.1  test.app   www.test.app
```

Two domain name all binded with  127.0.0.1.

cat   /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.hwy.local
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_hwy.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_hwy.log combined
        <Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName www.test.app
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot  /home/debian9/app
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_app.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_app.log combined
    <Directory /home/debian9/app>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Save the same file `test.html`  in both `/var/www/html` and `/home/debian9/app`.

```
<p>it is a test</p>
```

Why `www.hwy.local/test.html` can open it ,`www.test.app`  run into error.

```
This site can’t be reached
```

Comment: Look into `/var/log/apache2/error_app.log` and `/var/log/apache2/access_app.log`. Also add the output of `namei -olm /home/debian9/app/index.html`.

Comment: The permissions problem is because you've configured the second vhost to keep its files in a subdirectory under `/home` instead of under `/var/www/html`. Do a search for "apache directory permissions" on this site, and you'll find lots of similar questions that will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't with Apache, it's with your `/etc/hosts` file.

You can only have one line in the hosts file per IP address. So your hosts file should look like this:

```
127.0.0.1  hwy.local  www.hwy.local  test.app   www.test.app
```

with all the entries for 127.0.0.1 on one and the same line.

Comment: issure remains here.

Comment: You don't have permission to access /test.html

Comment: When I answered, the issue you had was `Site can't be reached` and thaẗ́s what I answered. We generally prefer that people don't change the questions when they encounter a new problem, because it'll make the answer a lot less useful for other readers in the future.